Python large-scale data format for distributed writing, reading, and storing on AWS
I'm trying to figure out the best way to write, read, and store data on AWS using a conventional Python data format. From my various Googling, I wasn't able to find a conclusive list of Big O notation run-times for adding operations. The best thing I could find was a textual overview of the popular file formats, where the author comes to the conclusion that no one format covers all use cases.
My use case is as follows:
, but here's the specific use case I'm looking at:

I have a dataset which can be indexed by "sample_id". There are 2M to 8M such samples.
I would have some function to generate data for each sample. The generated data would be one fixed-length embedding per sample (basically a NumPy or PyTorch array 200 float16 values)
The data generation would be happening across multiple GPUs or in a multithreaded context
I want to quickly append these arrays in a (key, value) fashion to a into a single (or sharded) big file  [ideally O(1) insertion time]
Ideally, if the key already exists, I'd be overwriting the value
Once the data generation is complete, I'd plan on transferring the big file (or sharded files) to an S3 bucket
Later on, in another machine, I'll download the data from S3
Subsequently, I'd like my modeling code to read out specific embeddings from the big data file (or shards) using a key  [so ideally O(1) read time]
I'm willing to forgo space efficiency if that means improved read/write time

The datasets I'm processing will probably have somewhere between 2 million to 8 million rows (meaning there will be 2M to 8M keys). And the file formats I'm considering as of now are:

.npy
.hd5
.parquet
.csv

In my current work flow, I was saving individual NPY files, which is definitely a workaround to the distributed-ness of my problem. But transferring all the data to and from AWS becomes cumbersome when I have to do recursive uploads/downloads.
Would appreciate any advice on the best approach here! Similar to the above, I'd also be curious what would be the best format if the data I wanted to save was a JSON object.

"I want to store the data on AWS" Can you be more specific? AWS has multiple storage options with different trade-offs. For example, if you wanted to use S3, then that means that random access writes are not possible.

Hi @NickODell thanks for double-checking, yes, I mean that I want the files stored on S3 in the end.

"I have a dataset which can be indexed by "sample_id". There are 2M to 8M such samples." Can you clarify the data type of "sample_id"? Is it string/integer/vector? How big is it?

I did intend on keeping string-based keys (e.g., "datasetname_train_000124571"), but if integer based keys leads to some other optimality, I could switch gears.

Here's what I would suggest:
When creating your embeddings, use your current solution, and create lots of little .npy files.
Once you've created your embeddings, and you know how many there are, pack them into two files.
The first file is a .npy file with an array containing every embedding, of shape (N, 200). With memory mapping, you can create arrays much bigger than memory.
The second file is a shelf. This file maps the "sample_id" key into an integer. The integer represents an index into the array.
When you want to find an embedding, do this:
array[shelf[sample_id]]

i.e. look up the sample_id in the shelf, then look up the index of the embedding in the array.
If you memory-map the npy file into memory, and use the shelf, you can load single embeddings into memory without having the entire dataset in memory. However, it would require downloading the entire file from S3 before using it.

Thanks for this! I'm curious, is packing (stacking) all the embeddings into a single big .npy file a better idea than to say use a .npz file or .h5 file (both of which have a key-based accessing concept)?

.npz files are compressed, which means that you don't have random access to particular indices. You could load the entire array into memory, though. That'd work. Alternately, you could make 1 file within the .npz file per embedding, but I'm not sure how an .npz file, which is essentially a zip file, would handle millions of arrays. Can't comment on .h5.

Edit:
Your clarifications have cleared things up a bit in terms of your goals. So you want to store embeddings in files, which you transfer to S3 after creating them locally, but always intend on downloading the entire files before using them again locally. You want to store and access your embeddings using an integer key called sample_id as a key, and possibly want to add more metadata in the future, which you'd expect to conform to json.
Now I'd like to address the accepted answer by Nick ODell, which may work, but seems like a potentially hairy choice unless I'm still not understanding your problem. Your question states that this is meant to be a "distributed system", which implies multiple machines are reading/writing data. This is not possible with shelve/dbm unless you implement some kind of locking mechanism to control which machine currently has access to a given npy+dbm pair of files. This is what I meant in my original answer by "rolling your own database", which is almost universally considered an antipattern.
Additionally, using pickle to serialize data seems like an odd choice given your constraints. On the plus side, pickle is extremely flexible, allowing you to store not just JSON data, but arbitrary python objects. On the negative side, you're introducing a potential security issue by using a turing complete storage format. We may think about pickle files as a storage format, but from a security perspective it's more like storing an arbitrary computer program which can be used to recreate your python objects. If a bad guy ever got access to either S3 or dbm files on your/coworkers machines, they can put an arbitrary computer program in there that does literally anything a bad guy could want given the user's permissions.
I will happily go further into how I might solve this problem, but I first want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding anything here about the distributed nature of your problem.

Original Answer / Request for Clarification:
It's unclear exactly what your application is, and why you'd want to access these embeddings one at a time. Most applications of embeddings like a RAG-type workflow involve storing embeddings in a specialized database called a vector database, which is optimized for performing approximate nearest neighbor searches, which generally return more than one result.
If your goal is to access data from a remote disk as quickly as possible, I would strongly suggest using some form of database directly. These file formats certainly have their uses, but you may very well end up spending more time rolling your own database on top of S3 (what it sounds like you're using) rather than working on your actual problem.
Also, it's worth mentioning that your request is also a bit confusing when it comes to how you're phrasing your performance concerns. O(1) is great, and relevant to the storage/database implementation itself, but network overhead can be massive, especially if you are indeed accessing these embedding vectors one at a time. If you want performance of any kind, you'll want either very low latency or to access records in bulk.
It may be helpful for you to clarify your needs further. Feel free to respond to my comment or edit your original question if you have additional info or concerns.

Hey Evan, thanks for asking for clarification. I can edit the post above to describe the exact use case more explicitly.

@AswinSivaraman Sorry I missed your updates last night. I'm still not 100% confident I understand your problem completely, but I would strongly suggest you consider my comments on not rolling your own database if your problem is indeed distributed across more than one machine.
